# Remove text from string after a certain character in C

Tags: c, string, char, strip, ansi-c

I am reading lines from a file, the lines look like this:

```
89f81a03eb30a03c8708dde38cf:000391716
```

The thing is: I want to remove everything after the `:` (including the `:`).
I tried everything I could find online but they seem to use `const char` and the lines are `char` pointers.

Comment: Remove from where? If it is in a string (char array) just replace the `':'` with `'\0'`.

Comment: save the string into a mutable array of chars. Then use a loop to iterate through each character one at a time, once you reach your destination character, put a null character in that slot.

Comment: The lines are char arrays, forgot to add that, sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `strchr`:

```
char str[] = "89f81a03eb30a03c8708dde38cf:000391716";
char *ptr;

ptr = strchr(str, ':');
if (ptr != NULL) {
    *ptr = '\0';
}
```